# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have to create a function that will find the smallest `m` for which `n` is an integer. `n=(r/(R-r))*m`

I keep getting the error: `local variable 'n' referenced before assignment.` I tried using global `n` at the beginning of my function but then I get error : `name 'n' is not defined` Help would be much appreciated. Thank you. Here is my code:

```
def courbeFerme(R,r):
    global n
    if (R in range(0,1000)) and (r in range(0,1000)):
        m=0
        while ((r/(R-r))*m).is_integer()==False: 
            m+=1
            n=(r/(R-r))*m           
        return n
```

Comment: Why is `n` global? Global variables are usually unnecessary and a sign of badly thought-out code.

Answer (score 3):

If your `while` loop's conditional fails on the first test, you never assign to `n`, but you still try to `return` it. You need to either:

1. Ensure that assignment always occurs at least once, or
2. Give `n` a default value at global scope, so it has something to read even if you don't assign to it in the function.

If it's not to be a `global`, the same solution applies, but you have to give it a default value on entry to the function.

Comment: @pts: It won't raise `UnboundLocalError` if you keep the `global` declaration in the function. Options #1 and 2 both apply to the posted code (which has a `global n` declaration). The final paragraph notes how it has to change if it's not a `global`. [Simplified example](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P0/BVsGUKyU1TSEtP1@jQtOKSwEI0nPykxJzFPLAnMw0hQoFOwVDiBQIgDRVKGgrGIJFilJLSovygIq5Cooy80o0QAYZaGoi8QyNNDX//wcA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: ok so if I say n=0 outside my function that is #2 right? (sorry very new to coding). And also when you say this (If your while loop's conditional fails on the first test, you never assign to n, but you still try to return it.) you mean I should also say n=... outside of the while? By the way thank you so much for giving an answer. :)

Comment: @RafaelGonzalez: Yes, replacing `global n` with `n = 0` will fix the `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @pts sorry to bother you but could you check my answer please.